# Convert Access Query to VB.net SQL Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I have a table in my Access database called `Historical_Stock_Prices` that is filled with various companies historical stock prices.  I need to run a query that will convert the raw data (the stock prices) into quarterly growth rates and display the quarterly growth rates in a `DataGridView`.

I've already written the the following query in the SQL View of my Access database and it works within Access.

`SELECT MinMaxYrQtrDates.YrQtr, MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker, MinMaxYrQtrDates.MaxDate, [Historical Prices].Close, MinMaxYrQtrDates.MinDate, [Historical Prices_1].Open, ([Historical Prices].[Close]/[Historical Prices_1].[Open]-1)*100 AS GrowthRate
FROM [Historical Prices] AS [Historical Prices_1] INNER JOIN ([Historical Prices] INNER JOIN [SELECT Year([Date]) & "-" & DatePart("q",[Date]) AS YrQtr, [Historical Prices].Ticker, Max([Historical Prices].Date) AS MaxDate, Min([Historical Prices].Date) AS MinDate
FROM [Historical Prices]
GROUP BY Year([Date]) & "-" & DatePart("q",[Date]), [Historical Prices].Ticker]. AS MinMaxYrQtrDates ON ([Historical Prices].Date = MinMaxYrQtrDates.MaxDate) AND ([Historical Prices].Ticker = MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker)) ON ([Historical Prices_1].Ticker = MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker) AND ([Historical Prices_1].Date = MinMaxYrQtrDates.MinDate);`

I need to be able to call it from within my program and display the results in a `DataGridView`.  I've tried to copy the SQL statement from Access and use it as the SQL statement in my code but it doesn't work.  I don't get any errors, the `DataGridView` is just blank.  Here is my code so far:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Historical_Growth_Rates_Annual

Public tblName As String = "Historical_Stock_Prices"

Private Sub Historical_Growth_Rates_Annual_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If (File.Exists(Nordeen_Investing_3.databaseName)) Then
        Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Open()
        Dim restrictions(3) As String
        restrictions(2) = tblName
        Dim dbTbl As DataTable = Nordeen_Investing_3.con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
        If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Historical Stock Prices tables does not exist in the database.  Please Update")
        Else
            Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MinMaxYrQtrDates.YrQtr, MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker, MinMaxYrQtrDates.MaxDate, [Historical_Stock_Prices].Close1, MinMaxYrQtrDates.MinDate, [Historical_Stock_Prices_1].Open1, ([Historical_Stock_Prices].[Close1]/[Historical_Stock_Prices_1].[Open1]-1)*100 AS GrowthRate FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] AS [Historical_Stock_Prices_1] INNER JOIN ([Historical_Stock_Prices] INNER JOIN [SELECT Year([Date1]) & " - " & DatePart('q',[Date1]) AS YrQtr, [Historical_Stock_Prices].Ticker, Max([Historical_Stock_Prices].Date) AS MaxDate, Min([Historical_Stock_Prices].Date) AS MinDate FROM [Historical_Stock_Prices] GROUP BY Year([Date1]) & " - " & DatePart('q',[Date1]), [Historical_Stock_Prices].Ticker]. AS MinMaxYrQtrDates ON ([Historical_Stock_Prices].Date = MinMaxYrQtrDates.MaxDate) AND ([Historical_Stock_Prices].Ticker = MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker)) ON ([Historical_Stock_Prices_1].Ticker = MinMaxYrQtrDates.Ticker) AND ([Historical_Stock_Prices_1].Date = MinMaxYrQtrDates.MinDate);", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
            'create a new dataset
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            'fill the datset
            da.Fill(ds)
            'attach dataset to the datagrid
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ds = Nothing
            da = Nothing
            Nordeen_Investing_3.con.Close()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Database does not exist.  Please update.")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm really stuck and could use some help!  Thanks!

[image: Database Example]

Comment: No errors?  Hmm.  Try using single quotes on stuff like this: `DatePart('q'...`

Comment: @LarsTech Still blank.  No errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that VB.Net code to recreate the same `SELECT` statement which works in Access.  However, looking at the syntax highlighting with Vim, I think you may actually be creating something else.  (It may be like creating a string as the difference of 2 other strings: `"string 1" - "string 2"`).

But whether or not I guessed correctly, use a string variable to hold your `SELECT` statement.  Then print that string to the console or write it to a text file so that you can examine the actual statement you're giving to the db engine.

Or save the working query in Access as a named query object and use that query name from your VB.Net code --- that would absolutely guarantee using the same SQL which is confirmed to work in Access.

Comment: I think I understand your first suggestion and I will work with it and see what I come up with.  As for you second suggestion.  I've thought of this but in some instances I may need to create the database from scratch and if that happens the query would not be available for me to call by name.

Comment: Whatever approach is best, you really need to take another look at the SQL you claimed works in Access.  The db engine will choke when it tries to parse this segment: `INNER JOIN [SELECT Year([Date]) & "-" & DatePart("q",[Date]) AS YrQtr, [Historical Prices].Ticker, Max([Historical Prices].Date) AS MaxDate, Min([Historical Prices].Date) AS MinDate FROM [Historical Prices] GROUP BY Year([Date]) & "-" & DatePart("q",[Date]), [Historical Prices].Ticker]. AS MinMaxYrQtrDates`

Comment: When you try a subquery in the form of `[SELECT ...]. AS alias` instead of `(SELECT ...) AS alias`, Access will be confused by any additional `[]` characters within the subquery's `SELECT`.

Comment: The SQL worked in Access last year when I created it in Access.  See http://www.accessforums.net/queries/query-calculate-quarterly-growth-rate-33035.html for further insight.  Now I cannot get it to work.  I've since switched computers and I am working with Open Office instead of Access and I assumed the switch in programs was what caused the SQL to not work now since it used to work.  Regardless, any suggestions on what I can do to yield the results that I need?

Comment: Build the `SELECT` as a string variable.  Print the variable's content to a text file.  Copy the statement from the text file and try it in an Access session as a new query.

Comment: I tried this `Dim SQL_String As String = "SELECT ... MinMaxYrQtrDates.MinDate);"
                Debug.WriteLine(SQL_String)
                Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_String, Nordeen_Investing_3.con)`.  But my code doesn't even reach this point.  It reverts back to my main form to the code where the `Historical_Growth_Rates_Annual` is called from and exits the code showing the blank `DataGridView` without any errors.

Comment: @nordeen1 `my code doesn't even reach this point.`  You will have to explain that part.

Comment: I can help with Access SQL.  I'm lost when it comes to `.Net`.  But I know just enough to tell you can't expect Access SQL to work from `.Net` if it doesn't work in Access.  Create an Access query which you can **verify** actually works in Access.  Then use that same SQL statement in `.Net`.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm slightly baffled by what happened here.  The code just jumps from the current form back to the original.  before I even get the the `Debug.Writeline` portion of the code.

Comment: @nordeen1 Try moving your code out of the Load event and into the Shown event.  I'm guessing you'll start seeing errors.

Comment: @HansUp I see what you are saying and it makes sense.  In theory, if I can get a code that works in SQL View in the database software, I should be able to copy that code into the SQL statement in VB.net and it should work without having to convert anything?  So in other words, the SQL statements are interchangeable between Access and VB.net?

Comment: @LarsTech I changed to the Shown event and the errors began to show.  This adds to clarity.  Thanks!

Comment: @nordeen1 Not in every case.  A query in Access might use functions which are not available outside Access.  And with OleDb `Like` wild cards must be `%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`.  But if your starting point is Access SQL which doesn't work in Access *now* (regardless of whether or not it worked in Access in the past), I'm afraid you're just totally screwed.  :-)

Comment: @HansUp Haha I appreciate the help.  I will start over on writing a correct SQL for what I need.  Any tips and direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good.  I didn't spot any functions in that Access SQL which would be unavailable when run from OleDb.  So you might be OK once you get working Access SQL.  If you have trouble creating the valid Access SQL, please make that a separate question and you can leave any mention of `.Net` out of that one.